# Invalid qlineargradient set in qt designer

Tags: css, qt, user-interface

In qt designer, I set a QLabel. And my stylesheet is like this:

QWidget#Title {
color: qlineargradient(x1:0,y1:0,x2:1,y2:1,stop: 0 green, stop: 1 red)
}

Title is the name of the Object.

But whatever I try, there isn't any change in view.
How to make it effective? thank you

Comment: I don’t know qt designer but are you sure color can be set to a linear gradient? It can’t in pure CSS